# How to set icon size in options Menu?

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I have created different drawable folders for my menu icons but the large icons show up on the small screens as well how can I set icons according to screen size in my options menu below also is it possible to reduce space between each icon?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:title=""
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:icon="@drawable/scan_qr_icon"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_icon"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Comment: Best practices for now is use svg icons(vector assets) as android drawable they auto set their size as screen requirements. don't need different png icons for screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mipmap-xhdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi, etc for icon

refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html

or use 50X50 images for icons and use .svg instead of .png/.jpg

Comment: Okay using the image asset studio helped but my icons are bright white and it made it a light grey even though it I used a custom white

Comment: @SnehaRaj By default, your icons will be tinted by the theme of your application. You can look into changing the tint color for the theme, removing tint from the menu, or changing the tint of individual icons to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

put icons with different size in drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi , drawable-xxhdpi ..Android will autometically get icons from drawable folder accroding to device screen.

Comment: then try to use vector-drawable .

Comment: Have you tested in different devices ?